# Live Sass Compiler doesn't compile ".min.css" nor ".map" files

Tags: css, json, visual-studio, sass

The issue is my Live SASS Compiler doesn't compile all files i set to create in settings.json file (placed in the next directory: [my-project]/.vscode/settings.json). Here's the copy of json settings i implemented for my project:

```
{
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "/css"
        },
        {
            "extensionName": ".min.css",
            "format": "compressed",
            "savePath": "/css"
        }
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [
        "**/node_modules/**",
        ".vscode/**"
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": true,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions"
    ]
}
```

Does anyone have any idea, why only  ".css" file is being created/changed every time I compile the scss code in my "main.scss" file and neither "min.css" nor ".map" files are created by Live CSS Compiler? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think there has to be a slash before .vscode.
Like this

```
"/**/node_modules/**",
"/.vscode/**"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes no difference...(

Answer (score 0):

```html
{
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
      {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "~/../css/"
      },
      {
        "extensionName": ".min.css",
        "format": "compressed",
        "savePath": "~/../css/"
      }
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [
      "**/node_modules/**",
      ".vscode/**"
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
      "> 1%",
      "last 2 versions"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when duplicating a copy of a project. Hit CTRL + P and edit the Live Sass compiler settings via the .settings file.

I was modifying the .settings file in projects root .vscode/settings.json but the .settings.json file being used was in my User directory. Hope this helps.